# How to share a record with a community user?

Tags: apex, community, security, customer-community, manual-sharing

I'm trying to share a record for a community user programatically. Tried below code in Execute anonymous.

```
// Create new sharing object for the custom object.
myObject__Share objShare  = new myObject__Share();

// Set the ID of record being shared.
objShare.ParentId = 'a0Vf4000001Hprq'; //recordId;

// Set the ID of user or group being granted access.
objShare.UserOrGroupId = '005f4000000vjvX';

// Set the access level.
objShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';

insert objShare;
```

But unfortunately it fails with error "Line: 14, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (invalid user or group: 005f4000000vjvX): [unknown]" .

[image]

Is it not possible to grant sharing access to community users via manual sharing? I could not find a related documentation on it. Or should I set some configuration settings for this?
Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

> Note: This could have been achieved using [Sharing sets in Community
>   settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=0), but due to design constraints I'm not able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the [related documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0) on this.

> Roles and Advanced Sharing is not available for Customer Community
>   user.

[image]

Comment: and I managed to get the required design changes to add contact lookup on the object, and do it using Sharing sets in Community settings.

Answer (score 0):

Customer community users cannot participate in advanced sharing. This can be worked around in 2 ways:
 1.'with sharing' can be removed from class signature allowing updates/reads from within the class.
                                       2.The ownerId of this record can be changed to point it to the Contact's ->UserId.
  So, here     objShare.OwnerID = CustomercommunityContact->UserID

Comment: Hi @Shalini, Thanks for the reply. 1st one is not recommended I believe. 2nd one I tried, and that is the one caused error. Was it successful for you? Probably I guess it's again 'Without sharing'.

Comment: I tried both options and they worked for different scenarios. What is the error you are getting on the 2nd one?

Comment: "Line: 14, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (invalid user or group: 005f4000000vjvX): [unknown]"

Comment: Can you paste the code as well.

Comment: If you could please read my question again once more, the code and this error is mentioned there.

Comment: I thought you are changing the ownerId? and not creating a sharing object?Can you please execute changing the ownerId on 1 record from dev console and let me know how you go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68425/discussion-between-pasan-eeriyagama-and-shalini-mendu).